# Is it possible to Insert off an Insert into a different table?

Tags: sql-server

I am tasked with entering 6000 records into our postgres db. These records need to be entered into two separate tables for our app to function properly, the containers table which creates a container id, which then needs to be used in the movements table.

Is it possible to automate the record creation, 1 entry at a time, first in the containers table, grabbing the container id and using it in the movement record creation as these need to made at the same time, or I have no way of matching the records. These are older records from before this section of our app.

I can use pgadmin or sql management studio to accomplish this task as I have the two sql servers linked, if one has an easier way of accomplishing this

I am not sure if this will make it more clear, but below is the container record I need to create and after that is created I need that id to then make the movement record

```
----Container
INSERT INTO containers (name, children, type, gross, created_at, updated_at, batch, tare, phase, bovedaCount, parent, isVerified, isSterilized, product, isFlagged)
  SELECT 
       [Box Number]
       ,NULL [children]
       ,5 [type]
       ,[Gross (g)]
       ,[Boxed Date] [created_at]
       ,GETDATE()
       ,b.id [Batch ID]
       ,[Tare (g)]
       ,NULL [phase]
       ,[Moisture Pck qty]
       ,NULL [parent]
       ,NULL [isVerified]
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
  FROM [boxRecords] br
  LEFT JOIN batches b ON b.name = br.Batch
  ORDER BY b.id
```

```
---Movement
 INSERT INTO movements (amount, description, labour, created_by, batch, strain, phase, product, container, location, type, created_at, updated_at)
  SELECT 
        c.gross + c.tare,
        NULL [Description],
        NULL [Labour],
        1 [Created_by],
        b.id [BatchID],
        b.strain [Strain],
        p.id [Phase],
        pt.id [ProductID],
        ---c.id [ContainerID],---- This part is the hard part
        1531 [LocationID],
        2 [Type],
        [Boxed Date] [Created_at],
        GETDATE() [Updated_at]
  FROM [Finance].[dbo].[boxRecords] br
  LEFT JOIN batches b ON b.name = br.Batch
  LEFT JOIN producttypes pt ON br.Description = pt.abbreviation
  LEFT JOIN phases p ON b.id = p.batch
  WHERE p.type = 7
  ORDER BY b.id
```

This is a one time deal as our app now does this, I have 6000 records, where it needs to create 1 container record and then 1 movement record after it.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for triggers

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name triggers get created on the table, so this will need to be done after hours when no users are entering data, as I dont want to replicate their entries, correct?

Comment: You lost me. I thought you want to copy inserted rows into a different table. Is that a one-time job or something you always want to do? With Postgres you could do `with insert_one as ( insert into table_one (....) values (..),(..) returning *) insert into table_two (...) select ... from insert_one` - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I removed the `postgresql` tag as you are clearly using SQL Server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just happened to be on the SQL Server when I started

Answer (score 0):

As the following sample code indicates that your first job is to **find out the unique key of boxRecords** and replace BoxNumber with it in the sample. If there is no unique key of boxRecords, you could use some trickes like using order to find *top 1* value of `@ContainersTableVar` for each *movement* record.

```
      DECLARE @ContainersTableVar table(BoxNumber varchar(8), ContainerId int);  
      --Assume [Box Number] of boxRecords are unique. Datatypes of BoxNumber and containerId should be datatypes of [boxRecords].[BoxNumber] and [ContainerID]
                
      ----Container
      INSERT INTO containers(
            name, 
            children, 
            type, 
            gross, 
            created_at, 
            updated_at, 
            batch, 
            tare, 
            phase, 
            bovedaCount, 
            parent, 
            isVerified, 
            isSterilized, 
            product, 
            isFlagged)
      OUTPUT INSERTED.name, INSERTED.Id INTO @ContainersTableVar --The Id should be the name of containers' id field name    
      SELECT 
            [Box Number]
            ,NULL [children]
            ,5 [type]
            ,[Gross (g)]
            ,[Boxed Date] [created_at]
            ,GETDATE()
            ,b.id [Batch ID]
            ,[Tare (g)]
            ,NULL [phase]
            ,[Moisture Pck qty]
            ,NULL [parent]
            ,NULL [isVerified]
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
      FROM [boxRecords] br
      LEFT JOIN batches b ON b.name = br.Batch
      ORDER BY b.id
    
    
      ---Movement
      INSERT INTO movements(amount, description, labour, created_by, batch, strain, phase, product, container, location, type, created_at, updated_at)
      SELECT 
            c.gross + c.tare,
            NULL [Description],
            NULL [Labour],
            1 [Created_by],
            b.id [BatchID],
            b.strain [Strain],
            p.id [Phase],
            pt.id [ProductID],
            (SELECT CVar.ContainerId FROM @ContainersTableVar AS CVar WHERE CVar.BoxNumber = br.[Box Number]) [ContainerID],---- This part is the hard part
            1531 [LocationID],
            2 [Type],
            [Boxed Date] [Created_at],
            GETDATE() [Updated_at]
      FROM [Finance].[dbo].[boxRecords] br
      LEFT JOIN batches b ON b.name = br.Batch
      LEFT JOIN producttypes pt ON br.Description = pt.abbreviation
      LEFT JOIN phases p ON b.id = p.batch
      WHERE p.type = 7
      ORDER BY b.id
```

Comment: the tables have an id field it is set to auto, thats why I did not add it on the insert. Field like box number are the names of fields I received in the excel sheet, it is just a name field

Comment: If you could provide the data structures of each table, I could change the sample code to be more exact.

Comment: The data structure is what is in the Insert statement, the only thing its missing is the table id as its auto increment

Comment: @Mike Does [boxRecords] table have any unique key and what is its name?